# Require help understand design "Named Template Arguments"

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading [this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cplusplus/0201734842/templates-and-design/ch16) chapter, I couldn't get the design, I just understood that somehow we want to evade filling some default parameter arguments i.e

```
template< typename T=int , typename V = float> struct foo;
foo</*evade first type argument, */ char> ha;
```

This whole sentence also eluded me due to which I guess I'm not getting whole thing :

> Our technique consists of placing the default type values in a base
>   class and overriding some of them through derivation. Instead of
>   directly specifying the type arguments, we provide them through helper
>   classes. For example, we could write `BreadSlicer<Policy3_is<Custom> >`.
>   Because each template argument can describe any of the policies, the
>   defaults cannot be different. In other words, at a high level every
>   template parameter is equivalent...................

yes I'm unable to understand the thing already explained thing :(. Please help me understanding how all things are working together integrated. Thanks

Comment: Do you understand the problem they are trying to solve? The first thing to understanding the solution is understanding the problem: *Given a template with M arguments for which there are default values, how can I change the value of the nth argument without having to explicitly state all of the previous (n-1) arguments?*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yes I guess, which I already described in question what I understood, thanks

Comment: What is it that you don't understand, the *sentence* or the *solution* that is explained in the chapter. The sentence does not sound that *complex*: create a base class that has the default argument types, then through inheritance override some of them. Or are you asking about the implementation of that solution?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'm unable to understand the solution explanation (Whole design rationale).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly you are asking about how the overall design works. 
The problem to solve is being able to provide a value for one of the template arguments without having to provide it for all of the previous arguments. And the solution is to move the types from being arguments to the template to being typedefs in a base class, and then masking some of the specific typedefs with the arguments to the modified template.

In some short of pseudo code, where the user said:

```
 X< default1, default2, override3 >  // forced to provide default1 and default2!
```

We want her to say:

```
 X< modifyArgument3With< override3 > >
```

The solution that they propose is creating a type hierarchy, where the base holds the default values:

```
struct DefaultPolicies {
   typedef Default1 P1;
   ...
   typedef DefaultN PN;
};
```

And then masking the base types through inheritance. Think for simplicity of manually defining a derived type `MyPolicies` like:

```
struct MyPolicies : DefaultPolicies {
    typedef OverrideX PX;
    typedef OverrideY PY;
};
```

If you do: `MyPolicies::PX` or `MyPolicies::PY` you will get the overrides, but for any other type `PN` you will get the default type defined in the base class.

Now what you need is to be able to construct the `MyPolicies` equivalent automagically. For this they build a parallel type hierarchy with virtual inheritance to create `PolicySelector` (which is the equivalent of `MyPolicies`). I believe this could also be done with a linear hierarchy (this is the type of solution that Alexandrescu provides in *Modern C++ Design*), but that requires the use of type lists that add extra code. In C++11 the linear hierarchy becomes much simpler with variadic template arguments, but in C++98 you would have to write quite a bit just to support the list.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Your explanation really made sense to me, Thanks a lot :)